# Cinema 4d export to Illustrator with texture

Tags: adobe-illustrator, uv-mapping, cinema-4d

I need little help with exporting from Cinema 4d to illustrator. The idea is I want to use body paint in c4d and then I want to export to Illustrator the model with my body paint work (not just grey model). Is it possible? The Idea is I create 3d model for my game but this models must be with precise dimensions. In Cinema 4d have measurement in centimeters, meters etc without pixels. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm very confused about what exactly you're trying to do.
You want to render a model inside C4D and texture, then use it inside Illustrator as an asset/sprite?
That's totally possible you just need to render the model with alpha.

And yes Cinema4d has measurement system:
Go to Edit -> User Preferences -> Units